# Cannot INSERT into SQLite table using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

My button on click looks like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ticket.Details td = new ticket.Details();

    td.@ref = txtRef.Text;
    td.subject = txtSubject.Text;
    td.contact_name = txtContact_Name.Text;
    td.company_name = txtCompany_Name.Text;
    td.description = rtDescription.Text;
    td.business_impact = rtBusiness_Impact.Text;
    td.severity = txtSeverity.Text;

    var ticket = new ticket();

    ticket.AddTicket(td);
}
```

`AddTicket` looks like this:

```
public int AddTicket(Details details)
{
        const string query = "INSERT INTO support(ref, subject, contact_name, company_name, description, business_impact, severity) VALUES (@ref, @subject, @contact_name, @company_name, @description, @business_impact, @severity)";

        //here we are setting the parameter values that will be actually 
        //replaced in the query in Execute method
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"@ref", details.@ref},
    {"@subject", details.subject},
    {"@contact_name", details.contact_name},
    {"@company_name", details.company_name},
    {"@description", details.description},
    {"@business_impact", details.business_impact},
    {"@severity", details.severity}
    };

    return ExecuteWrite(query, args);
}
```

When I look at:

```
return ExecuteWrite(query, args);
```

I can see that query is:

```
INSERT INTO support(ref, subject, contact_name, company_name, description, business_impact, severity) 
VALUES (@ref, @subject, @contact_name, @company_name, @description, @business_impact, @severity)
```

And args is **7**

My `ExecuteWrite` looks like this:

```
private int ExecuteWrite(string query, Dictionary<string, object> args)
{
    int numberOfRowsAffected;

    // setup the connection to the database
    using (var con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=main.db"))
    {
        con.Open();

        // open a new command
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con))
        {
            // set the arguments given in the query
            foreach (var pair in args)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }

            cmd.Prepare();

            // execute the query and get the number of row affected
            numberOfRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        return numberOfRowsAffected;
    }
}
```

Everything looks good, my `numberOfRowsAffected` is showing 1 row and my args is 7 which is correct.

I am getting no error but I just don't see any data affected in my `main.db` SQLite database file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you `commit` the changes somewhere in your code?

Comment: @GMB: No, I click Save, it goes to AddTicket, and then goes ExecuteWrite.

Comment: @LarsTech: I would like to execute the query passing in the 7 params.

Comment: @LarsTech: I thought `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` would execute the query?

Comment: I think I misread your question thinking you were expecting 7 rows.  A return of 1 means it worked.  You are maybe looking at the wrong database?

Comment: @LarsTech, the file is called `main.db` and the table inside it is called `support`, every field in there is nullable. So I dont understand why its not worked.

Comment: You aren't providing a path in your connection string, so it assumes the database is in the same directory as the executable.  During development, that's most likely in the bin\debug folder.

Comment: @LarsTech: I am being a total baffoon here. The main.db is in \bin\Debug folder and I am using SQL LIte Browser to read a different main.db

Answer (score 1):

The `main.db`  was actually located in `\bin\Debug` as such it was working fine!
Just remember if you are reading the DB using DB Browser for SQL Lite, then be sure to load the correct db!